# Sharepoint with MFA not allowing access

Tags: c#, azure, sharepoint, azure-active-directory

We use Multi-factor authentication on our Sharepoint. We are trying to download some documents from sharepoint to manipulate in our application. I have tried to access the sharepoint using both the "traditional" method as well as trying to go thru our Azure AD. Both methods dont allow us to access the sharepoint - we get permission denied

Any help would be greatly appreciated

This is what i have tried already - going thru AD

```
string clientId = "xxx";
string clientSecret = "yyy";
string tenant = "zzz";

AuthenticationResult result = null;
var data = AzureAdOptions.Settings.Authority;
AuthenticationContext authContext = new 
AuthenticationContext(AzureAdOptions.Settings.Authority);

ClientCredential credential = new 
ClientCredential(AzureAdOptions.Settings.ClientId, 
AzureAdOptions.Settings.ClientSecret);

result = await 
 authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(AzureAdOptions.Settings.PreceptWebApiResourceId, credential);

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);

request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

and then the more "traditional way"

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://my.sharepoint.com:/sites/files/");

string userName = "mylogon";
string password = "@!";

var securePassword = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in password)
{
    securePassword.AppendChar(c);
}

request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, securePassword);

String encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(userName + ":" + password));

request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Have you assigned any permissions on the app in Azure AD?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line of code below

```
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, securePassword);
```

with

```
request.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);
```

Or using [SharePointPnPCoreOnline](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharePointPnPCoreOnline).

```
var authManager = new AuthenticationManager();
var ctx = authManager.GetWebLoginClientContext("https://contoso.sharepoint.com/");
```

Refer to: [CSOM.MFA.cs](https://gist.github.com/vman/37bab1e1d700be238011f1de23a3e275)